# min/max based on property (not attribute) of class object in python

Tags: python, properties, key

Consider the following snippet of codes.

```
class MyClass(object):
  @property
  def foo(self):
    return self._foo      

l = [my_class1, my_class2]

min(l, key=MyClass.foo) # doesn't work because foo is not callable. 
                        # "TypeError: 'property' object is not callable"
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Using a property is exactly the same as using an instance attribute in most cases, including this one. So, the same solutions that work for normal attributes (`attrgetter`, or of course an explicit function via lambda or def that accesses it as an attribute) will work here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`operator.attrgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
min(l, key=operator.attrgetter('foo'))
```

---

Example:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self._foo = val
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'MyClass({})'.format(self._foo)
...     @property
...     def foo(self):
...         return self._foo
... 
>>> import operator
>>> min([MyClass(3), MyClass(1), MyClass(2)], key=operator.attrgetter('foo'))
MyClass(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda expression to access foo just as though it were an attribute:

```
min(l, key=lambda o: o.foo)
```